# Mongo template not returning all records

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

criteria = Criteria.where("gstin").in(gstinList);
in db gstin number 1234, 123, 1234.
when i want to retrieve the gstlin list by giving input 1234, 123, i am getting only 2 records not 3 records.
what is the issue here not able to get it